# Emacs 23.3.1: whitespace style

Tags: whitespace, emacs23

I've just upgraded to Kubuntu 11.10. After that the way Emacs represents whitespace in whitespace minor mode got changed. It were shaded rectangulars and not Emacs puts dots in the place of white space:

[image]

I tried to change it through the `M-x customize-group` and then `whitespace` -- but there's no such thing as a dot. It says that whitespaces are represented by shading (see the pic above) - but they are not (see the same pic).

Here's the value of Whitespace Space face:

[image]

I also asked this question at [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/347869/emacs-whitespace-style) but since I got 0 replies there -- I decided to consult another community.

**Edit 1**:

Following the Luke's solution gives no coloring to space nor to tabs (unless I've done something wrong):

[image]

**Edit 2**:

Adding `face` here fixes Luke's solution. Thanks to Sergey.

```
(setq whitespace-style (quote
   ( face spaces tabs newline space-mark tab-mark newline-mark)))
```

**Edit 3**:

Currently I'm using:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(whitespace-line-column 9999999)
 '(whitespace-tab-width 4 t)
 '(whitespace-display-mappings '(
    (space-mark ?\ [?\u00B7] [?.])                 ; space - centered dot
    (space-mark ?\xA0 [?\u00A4] [?_])            ; hard space - currency
    (newline-mark ?\n [?$ ?\n])                      ; eol - dollar sign
    (tab-mark ?\t [?\u00BB ?\t] [?\\ ?\t])       ; tab - left quote mark
                               ))
 '(whitespace-style '(face spaces tabs newline space-mark tab-mark newline-mark))
 )

(custom-set-faces 
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "#ffffb1" :foreground "#141312" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 125 :width normal :foundry "monotype" :family "DejaVu Sans Mono"))))
 '(whitespace-trailing ((t (:background "grey99"))))
)
```

at Emacs 24.3.50.1

Comment: What's the value of 'Whitespace Space face' (third item from the top)?

Comment: @ Luke Girvin: I've uploaded the screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's probably a better way to do this, but adding this to your .emacs should work:

```
(setq whitespace-display-mappings
      '(
    (space-mark   ?\     [? ]) ;; use space not dot
    (space-mark   ?\xA0  [?\u00A4]     [?_])
    (space-mark   ?\x8A0 [?\x8A4]      [?_])
    (space-mark   ?\x920 [?\x924]      [?_])
    (space-mark   ?\xE20 [?\xE24]      [?_])
    (space-mark   ?\xF20 [?\xF24]      [?_])
    (newline-mark ?\n    [?$ ?\n])
    (tab-mark     ?\t    [?\u00BB ?\t] [?\\ ?\t])))

(custom-set-faces
 '(whitespace-space
   ((((class color) (background dark)) (:background "red" :foreground "white"))
    (((class color) (background light)) (:background "yellow" :foreground "black"))
    (t (:inverse-video t)))))
```

The standard value of `whitespace-display-mappings` uses a 'middle dot' for a space, the code above uses a standard space. You can change the colours for `whitespace-space` as required.

Comment: I've added the screenshot. Strange - but after putting Your code to .emacs - nor spaces nor tabs are highlighted.

Comment: Does it work if eval the code after starting Emacs with the -q flag?

Answer (score 5):

All you need is just add 'face' keyword along others in whitespace-style.
E.g.:

```
(setq whitespace-style (quote
  ( face spaces tabs newline space-mark tab-mark newline-mark)))
```

Comment: I tried that - You're right - adding `face` indeed fixes Luke's solution (second screenshot at the original post). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After using Luke Girvin advice and starting `emacs` with `-q` flag - Luke's solution worked. I found that the problem was

```
;; make whitespace-mode use just basic coloring
(setq whitespace-style (quote
  ( spaces tabs newline space-mark tab-mark newline-mark)))
```

these lines in `.emacs`. So I removed them, and then have used `customize-group` -> `whitespace` to make things this way:

[image]

So ithe problem is solved. Thanks Luke!